# Do you need separate IP addresses for each nameserver for an EC2 webserver?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, nameserver, ip-address, amazon-elastic-ip

Do you need separate elastic IP addresses for each nameserver - say NS1, NS2 - for an EC2 webserver?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. What does a webserver have to do with anything? Are you asking if two nameservers can have the same public IP address? If they did, what would make them two nameservers exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You need nameservers for a *domain* not for an ec2 instance or for a webserver. I suggest you use a managed DNS service like **AWS Route53** and don’t worry about running your own nameservers.

Comment: this doesn't exactly answer my question, since i have scripts on the EC2 server that automatically provisions new domains...

Comment: You can just as easily script R53 domain provisioning with [`aws` cli](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) or with [`dnscontrol`](https://github.com/StackExchange/dnscontrol).